# Finding region of integration

Tags: integration

Integrate$
\int\int\exp(\frac{x^{2}+y^{2}}{2})\text{d}x\text{d}y $  over  region R, bound by lines, $y=0, y=x$ and arcs of circles $x^{2}+y^{2}=1$ and $x^{2}+y^{2}=2$.

I could plot the above equatons on an $x-y$ plane. But couldn't find a common region since  they are not given in form if inequalities. How do I find the region of integration?

Comment: Is there nothing else specified, e.g. _"in the first quadrant"_?

Comment: I have edited to add the entire question.

Comment: If it really says _"over **a** region"_, I would pick the one in the first quadrant and go with that - it's probably more about the _method_ than about the _result_ anyway. Note that the region (and function) would benefit from switching to polar coordinates.

Comment: Sorry there's no 'a' but I get your point.

Answer (score 0):

There are four possible regions. The first one lies in the first quadrant, the second one lies in the first and second quadrant, the third one lies in the third quadrant and the fourth lies in the third and fourth quadrant. All of them are sectors of a ring formed by the two bounding circles.